# Selenium doesn't click on certain elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to click and uncheck certain check-boxes on this [**Website**](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/), I want to uncheck

1. The *SOCKS4/5* under Protocols
2. *Slow* and *Medium* under Speed
3. *Slow* and *Medium* under Connection time

So that the end result looks like:

[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
base_url = "http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/"
driver.get(base_url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@name='pr[]'])[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("sp[]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@name='sp[]'])[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("ct[]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@name='ct[]'])[2]").click()
```

But this code only unchecks slow and medium in Connection Time but doesn't uncheck the stated checkboxes in `1` and `2`. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the inputs are hidden.  The span after the input is visible though.  I'd try something like this:

```
(//input[@name='pr[]'])[2]/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: Nope no change at all :(

Comment: What driver do you use? We had a similar issue with styled checkboxes that was hidden on Firefox Driver v. 28 iirc.

Comment: @limelights I'm on firefox 29.0.1 BTW how did you fix your issues?

Comment: @KDawG We haven't yet, we're still waiting for the new driver to be released. Not sure if it has been updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to uncheck the SOCKS4/5 input using

```
a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='2']")
a.click()
```

EDIT: More generalized approach:

```
fieldsets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('fieldset')
protocol = [i for i in fieldsets if "protocol" in i.text.lower()][0]
sock_input = protocol.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="2"]')
sock_input.click()
```

You'll just have to repeat the previous steps for the 'speed' & 'connection time' fieldset entities